# Android: Retrieve int saved in PreferenceManager getDefaultSharedPreferences in another activity

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save data using default `Shared Preferences`, but cannot get this code working.

I cant retrieve an `int` value in another activity.

In my first activity, in `onCreate`, I want to create a `scorecounter` that counts up every time you receive points. It will be initiated on first run.

```
SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

if (preferences.getBoolean("first_run", true)) 
{   
editor.putInt("totalpoang", 0);
editor.commit();
    preferences.edit().putBoolean("first_time", false);
}
```

In my `Activity B` I want to retrieve the value, modify it, and then save it in preferences again.

```
SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
int poang = preferences.getInt(totalpoang, 0);
editor.putInt("antalpoang", totalpoang);
editor.commit();
```

However **I only get the error totalpoang cannot be resolved as a variable**.

I initialized it as a `int` in the first Activity, and I am trying to retrieve it as an `int`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
int poang = preferences.getInt(totalpoang, 0);
//editor.putInt("totalpoang", 0); // key is "totalpoang"
```

to

```
int poang = preferences.getInt("totalpoang", 0);
```

And then

```
editor.putInt("antalpoang", poang);
```

Comment: Do I have to add "" marks when it haven't been created in the new activity?

Comment: @user3061876 its a string an yes it needs "". it's like a key. you retrieve value using key. need to use the same key to retrieve the value. what was the key used here `editor.putInt("totalpoang", 0)` same use it when retrieving

Comment: @user3061876 is `totalpoang` an integer value? If so change `editor.putInt("totalpoang", totalpoang);` // key is "totalpoang" and value is totalpoang if you have int toatlpoang =2 or soemthing.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood after your second comment. My application is now working! Thank you for you help!
The problem was as you wrote that I didn't know the difference how to define a string and a value.

Thank you! :)